# Best way to start with smalltalk in a windows environment (win 7)

Tags: smalltalk

I am a c# developer and most of my friends are much smarter than me, and they laugh at me and start to swear at me in smalltalk. I want to learn this so that I might better be insulted at their insults... and maybe learn a thing or two in the process.

So, what is the best place to start with regard to smalltalk in a windows environment?

Comment: Now a day that your are on Windows or other os it matter less. Most of the smalltalk that your find is ported to most os. The community make the effort to port there software on the major os. Thanks to FOSS

Comment: @Linton Caldecott - "I want to learn this so that I might better be insulated at their insults." I don't think this question should have been closed! No better reason for asking a question than this! LOL

Answer (score 7):

The best current free Smalltalk is probably [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/). This currently out-performs its near relative [Pharo](http://www.squeak.org/), at least on my ancient box, but you should really take a look at both of them.

The big problem with Smalltalk is that there are no really high-quality text books. There's a list of free ones [here](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html), but I couldn't recommend any of them strongly. If you decide to use Squeak, take a look at [Squeak By Example](http://www.squeakbyexample.org/), which isn't too bad.

Comment: Kent Beck's Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns is really high quality, but it's not much of a teaching aid :)

Comment: @Frank Matter of opinion - I think all Beck's books are enormously overrated.

Comment: @Neil I've read you say so in comments elsewhere :) Different strokes for different folks, I guess. SBPP might suffer less than others, if you don't like Beck's writing style: it's chock-ful of short, to-the-point tips on using Smalltalk idiomatically. At any rate, I found it enormously helpful in learning Smalltalk.

Comment: Re textbooks: Andres Valloud's books are awesome.  I wrote a [review of "A Mentoring Course on Smalltalk"](http://seandenigris.com/blog/?p=573).  "Fundamentals of Smalltalk Programming Technique, Volume 1" is also very good.  They are both available on lulu.com

Answer (score 7):

Since you are on Windows, I will say you should try DCE (Dolphin Community Edition), It has every thing (Including better integration with the OS than Pharo or Squeak, especially the GUI).

The Professional Edition will take you one level up since it contains other extra get-in-the-flow tools plus the Delivery wizard to directly produce executables (in short EXEs).
It's more than enough for learning Smalltalk. It includes a Help file (containing fast intro to Smalltalk, a comprehensive coverage of the environment, pattern usage, and a nice gui example).

If you think you will stay for long on Windows (an environment issue, etc...) or as igouy said 'leverage your Windows experience', then by All means check [DCE](http://www.object-arts.com/downloads/downloads.html).

As an extra I suggest you download it, check the intro to Smalltalk in the Help file and later on enjoy these videos:

1. [A Better Hello World](http://www.object-arts.com/support/videos_files/2a3076623680900f3028003a682b9370-5.html)
2. [Fun with MS Speech library (ActiveX wizard sample tutorial)](http://www.object-arts.com/support/videos_files/86b3e6a83ad06612e8105b446e312d73-3.html)
3. [Interfacing with iTunes](http://www.object-arts.com/support/videos_files/d7ba6d60ceb435a0bf6eb1e96d220c36-0.html)
4. [Programming Animation with Dolphin](http://www.object-arts.com/support/videos_files/21163c4401ba2928d4e0c1ca319c04c7-1.html) (this shows the interactive
   nature of Smalltalk in general, still in Dolphin is integrated with
   Windows so you can play with Windows's windows and controls in an
   easy and thrilling way.)

and by the way it's addictive!

happy small talks with Dolphin Smalltalk ;)

Answer (score 5):

Whichever environment you pick to start playing with, don't forget to check out Stéphane Ducasse's collection of FREE (and LEGAL) Smalltalk books:
[Free Smalltalk Books](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice new website called [The World of Smalltalk http://www.world.st](http://www.world.st), where you can find a simple yet comprehensible entry to the Smalltalk world, from introduction and documentation to the blogs, mailing lists, dialects and frameworks.

On Windows there are Win-only Dolphin Smalltalk, free cross-platform Squeak and Pharo, and commercial VisualWorks.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

> So, what is the best place to start
>   with regard to smalltalk in a windows
>   environment?

Perhaps it would be best to leverage your familiarity with MS Windows - "Dolphin Smalltalk X6 is an object-oriented development environment for Microsoft Windows™."

Try the "free for personal/educational use" ["Community Edition" of Dolphin Smalltalk](http://www.object-arts.com/content/navigation/products/dce.html).

[Getting Started, Programming Cookbook, Tutorials, ...](http://www.object-arts.com/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Squeak, like Neil Butterworth said, and hang out on [squeak-dev](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/squeak-dev). The [beginners](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners) mailing list's a good place to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

Dolphin Smalltalk Pro is selling for USD 225. Where can I such a powerful, good that price.

My preferences are Smalltalk and Common Lisp, but the Common Lisp IDEs are expensive by comparison.

The only problem is, I'd have to use Windows, but that was a decision I already had made, after years of Linux (going nowhere in the application-selling domain).

Answer (score 1):

To get started, I would recommend a [seaside](http://www.seaside.st/download/pharo) one-click image. Seaside is a most interesting web-framework and the image is based on [Pharo](http://pharo-project.org/). There are a number of [screencasts](http://pharocasts.blogspot.com/) available.
The authors of SQB expanded the book and adapted it to Pharo at [Pharo-By-Example](http://www.pharobyexample.org/).
They have a high-volume development [mailing list](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/mailman/listinfo/pharo-project) and a [users list](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-users/). For seaside you'd want the [users list](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/seaside/). Seaside also has a [book](http://book.seaside.st) and the [tutorials](http://seaside.gemstone.com/tutorial.html) by James Foster
which I'd recommend you to look first at.

I do not find significant speed differences between Pharo and Squeak, but Pharo is much cleaner due to its developer focus. Squeak contains a lot more interesting tidbits.

If you find the one-click image (there is also one available in a Squeak version) not fast enough, the introduction of the cog vm will improve performance by a factor two or so.

On Windows you should make sure that your anti-virus software does not try to verify the changes file each time it is written, or your Smalltalk environment gets to be very slow.

For learning a lot (not recommended to start with) you should take a look at the [Moose](http://moosetechnology.org/) one-click image and the book by Doru.

Comment: Squeak one-click images here: http://squeakingalong.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/new-squeak-4-1-seaside-images/

Answer (score 1):

As Janko said, Pharo and Squeak are good Smalltalk implementations to start with, but I would also like to add [Cincom's WebVelocity](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/products/webvelocity/) which is a bit different.  It is a VisualWorks/Seaside based Smalltalk IDE in the browser.