# Which Smalltalk implementation do you recommend for beginner

Tags: smalltalk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to start with smalltalk in a windows environment (win 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448383/best-way-to-start-with-smalltalk-in-a-windows-environment-win-7)

I am going to make the acquaintance with Smalltalk and looking for the good implementaion for beginner.

I am working on Windows platform; main criterias :good tutorials and documentaion, active community.

Comment: Hopefully the answers here will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448383/best-way-to-start-with-smalltalk-in-a-windows-environment-win-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Squeak Smalltalk](http://squeak.org/), it's a very modern, open-source, newbie-friendly implementation of Smalltalk. Or even more modern, [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org) , a fork of Squeak which removes unessential code and serves as the reference implementation of [Seaside](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Seaside_%28software%29), a web application framework in Smalltalk.

Comment: Also, IMHO the best introductions to Squeak are the Laser Game tutorial and the Bots Inc. book. If you go for Pharo, take a look at the Pharo by Example book.

Answer (score 6):

A Smalltalk designed for Windows -

[Dolphin Community Edition](http://www.object-arts.com/products/dce.html)

[Dolphin Smalltalk Video Library](http://www.object-arts.com/support/videos.html)

[Dolphin Smalltalk Documentation](http://www.object-arts.com/downloads/docs/index.html)

[Dolphin Smalltalk Community](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.smalltalk.dolphin/topics?hl=en&pli=1)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of [VisualWorks](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/developer-community/trying-cincom-smalltalk/try-cincom-smalltalk/) myself. I think it's a little less quirky than Squeak/Pharo.